# Problems with creating a decision tree and splitting on an attribute?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, decision-tree, supervised-learning

So I'm trying to split on an attribute "Color" that has possible values (Blue,Green,Red,Orange,Pink).

I'm splitting on [entropy](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~shapiro/EE596/notes/InfoGain.pdf) values, and the best split can either be Multi-Way 5, Multi-Way 4, Multi-Way 3, or Binary. For example:

```
5: (Blue, Green,Red,Orange,Pink)

4: (Blue, Green), (Red), (Orange), (Pink)
   (Green,Pink), (Blue),(Red),(Orange)

3: (Red,Orange), (Blue,Green), (Pink)
   (Red,Blue), (Green, Orange), (Pink)

2: (Blue,Green,Red), (Orange,Pink)
   (Pink), (Blue, Green, Red, Orange)
```

And so on. But how can I make a comprehensive list of all the possible splits? Is there a specific algorithm I could use? Or how would I even know how many max possible combinations there are with this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

The best split according to entropy(Information Gain) will always be 5.

Recall when you split according to an attribute either you gain information about Y or if they are independent no information gain is there, i.e. Information Gain at every split is greater than equal to zero. So IG(cases 2:4)<= IG(Case 1) as case 2,3,4 can be made into case 1 by adding further splits which can only add Information and not lose it.

For IG at split >=0 refer to: [Can the value of information gain be negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289589/can-the-value-of-information-gain-be-negative).

In general in decision trees/RF you try to find a single split which gives highest IG for an attribute, and then compare across attributes and select one.