# Can the value of information Gain Ratio be negative?

Tags: machine-learning

The information gain `IG(Y|X) = H(Y) - H(Y|X) >= 0`, but can the information gain ratio be less than 0?

[Can the value of information gain be negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289589/can-the-value-of-information-gain-be-negative)

[Information gain ratio - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it can't.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio#Information_gain_ratio_calculation), the information gain ratio is defined by `IGR = IG/IV`, where `IGR` is information gain ratio, `IG` is information gain, and `IV` is information value (aka intrinsic value).

You already agree that `IG >= 0`, so we just have to show that `IV >= 0`.

In the context of decision trees, let `Ex` be the set of training examples, let `a` be some feature, and let `A` be the value of `a` in a randomly chosen example in `Ex`.
Then we can say that `IV = H(A)`, and one of the properties of entropy is [non-negativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Further_properties), so we get:
`IV = H(A) >= 0`.

Alternatively, we can deduce that `IV >= 0` directly from its [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_gain_ratio#Intrinsic_value_calculation) (this is very similar to what someone might do to show that entropy is non-negative):

[image: IV definition]

There are only set sizes in the left fraction, so it is non-negative.
The right fraction equals to the size of a set, divided by the size of some superset. Thus, the fraction must be `<= 1`. 
Therefore, the log of this fraction must be `<= 0`.
So the whole sum is `<= 0`, and we have a minus, so we get `IV >= 0`.

Note: it might be that `IGR = 0/0`, and so it is undefined. An example for such case is when the value of `a` is the same in all of the training examples.